# About giving up one's Life for G-D and Minhag

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, martyr

My question is concerning the times when Jews are - G-D forbid - being persecuted religiously and they can't transgress or stop performing mitzvot to the extent of  not changing Minhag.

Does this mean that if my personal Minhag on Pesach is to refrain from eating kitniot (although my Sephardic neighbors do eat it) that I would have to give up my life rather than break my Minhag of not eating that on Pesach?

Or is it just talking about general Jewish vs non-Jewish customs?

Comment: yehudis, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including our twenty-one other [tag:yehareg-veal-yaavor] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.